# How to find files older than X days on busybox?

Tags: file, find, busybox

I need to find files older than 1 month, files older than 1 week but younger than 1 month and younger than 1 week.

These are backups and need to remove all but one from each time period.

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

I use BusyBox v1.22.1

Thanks in advance.